# Sorting a list of lists according to length of sublists

Tags: ocaml

```
let rec insert cmp e = function 
  | [] -> [e] 
  | h :: t as l -> 
    if cmp e h <= 0 then e :: l 
    else h :: insert cmp e t

let rec sort cmp = function
  | [] -> []
  | h :: t -> insert cmp h (sort cmp t)

let length_sort lists =
  let lists = List.map (fun list -> List.length list, list) lists in
  let lists = sort (fun a b -> compare (fst a) (fst b)) lists in
  List.map snd lists;;
```

I want to know how work this fun a b -> compare (fst a) (fst b),
compare return 1 or -1, and what will give as variable to sort?
and List.map snd lists will remove the first element of every list in the lists?

Comment: `fst` and `snd` work on _tuples_ rather than lists. Communication in programming is crucial. Using terms correctly will save time and frustration.

Answer (score 2):

Functions in OCaml are first class values. We can pass them to and return them from functions.

A function is passed to `sort` (which we cannot test in this case without `insert` and any of its dependencies) to determine *how* to sort the list. Consider passing the standard polymorphic `compare` to `List.sort`:

```
utop # List.sort compare [1;2;7;3;4;0];;
- : int list = [0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 7]
```

If we create a custom comparison function that reverse that comparison, we get the opposite result:

```
utop # List.sort (fun a b -> compare b a) [1;2;7;3;4;0];;
- : int list = [7; 4; 3; 2; 1; 0]
```

In the case you're asking about, `fun a b -> compare (fst a) (fst b)` compares the first element of each tuple, which happens to be the length of each sublist which you generated in the previous step.

`List.map` works by also taking a function. In this case it applies it to each element in a list and returning a list of the results. The second element in each tuple is the original sublist, so you get a list of lists as the result of `List.map snd lists`.

Consider a simpler example of `List.map`:

```
utop # List.map (fun x -> x * 3 + 1) [1; 3; 5];;
- : int list = [4; 10; 16]
```

Note also that you could write your code without the extra steps:

```
let length_sort lists = 
  List.sort (fun a b -> compare (List.length a) (List.length b)) lists
```